# Android libgdx setScreen not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using this [project](https://github.com/GreedyGame/Aam-Aadmi-Runner) to learn how to make a libgdx game. I tried following tutorials online to setup a menu like this but it force closes when I click on the play button. The logcat says that there is an error where it says game.setScreen(new SelectScreen());

```
    MenuButton localMenuButton1 = new MenuButton(this, "", localTextButtonStyle1);
        localMenuButton1.addListener(new ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent paramAnonymousInputEvent, float paramAnonymousFloat1, float paramAnonymousFloat2)
            {
            game.setScreen(new SelectScreen(game)); 
            }
        });
```

I've searched all over the net trying to find a solution but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the logcat exception stacktrace please.

Comment: The logcat did output that there is "an error" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "paramAnonymousInputEvent" is in your scenario, but i use the below code for all my buttons, no problems with doing it this way as far as i know

```
        final TextButton btOptions = new TextButton("Options", skin, "default");

    btOptions.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override 
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            myGame.setScreen(new MyOptionsScreen(myGame));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to just sick with the way things were originally and just replace the images with what I need. Once I read more into the code I figured out how the buttons were working. Thank you again though. I will definitely use that approach in the future.